# java.lang.StackOverflowError in TestNg

Tags: java, testng

I have super simple project written in page object pattern and the only dependency is TestNg 7.5.

### Project structure:

- there are two page object classes (TextEditorTabPage and VisualEditorTabPage)
- there is one test class (Testclass) with one @Test annotation inside from where I can run the test

[Screen with the project structure]
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUt9z.png

### Classes content:

**TextEditorTabPage**

```
package pages;
public class TextEditorTabPage {
    VisualEditorTabPage VisualEditor = new VisualEditorTabPage();

    public void qwer (){
        System.out.println("gg");
    }
}
```

**VisualEditorTabPage**

```
package pages;

public class VisualEditorTabPage {
    TextEditorTabPage TextEditor = new TextEditorTabPage();
}
```

**Testclass**

```
package tests;


import pages.TextEditorTabPage;
import pages.VisualEditorTabPage;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class Testclass {
    TextEditorTabPage textEditor = new TextEditorTabPage();
    VisualEditorTabPage visualEditor = new VisualEditorTabPage();


    @Test
    public void test (){

    }


}
```

### Problem

When I run the test, I recieve StackOverFlow error:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class tests.Testclass
    at org.testng.internal.objects.InstanceCreator.newInstance(InstanceCreator.java:41)
    at org.testng.ITestObjectFactory.newInstance(ITestObjectFactory.java:18)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.instantiateUsingDefaultConstructor(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:178)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.createInstance(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:87)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.dispense(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:40)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.dispense(GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.java:28)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:106)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:136)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:129)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:101)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:66)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:465)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:333)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:176)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:635)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:221)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1342)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1318)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1160)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1092)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1060)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.InstanceCreator.newInstance(InstanceCreator.java:38)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at pages.VisualEditorTabPage.<init>(VisualEditorTabPage.java:3)
    at pages.TextEditorTabPage.<init>(TextEditorTabPage.java:4)
    at pages.VisualEditorTabPage.<init>(VisualEditorTabPage.java:4)
    at pages.TextEditorTabPage.<init>(TextEditorTabPage.java:4)
    at pages.VisualEditorTabPage.<init>(VisualEditorTabPage.java:4)
    at pages.TextEditorTabPage.<init>(TextEditorTabPage.java:4)
    at pages.VisualEditorTabPage.<init>(VisualEditorTabPage.java:4)
    at pages.TextEditorTabPage.<init>(TextEditorTabPage.java:4)
    at pages.VisualEditorTabPage.<init>(VisualEditorTabPage.java:4)
    at pages.TextEditorTabPage.<init>(TextEditorTabPage.java:4)
    at pages.VisualEditorTabPage.<init>(VisualEditorTabPage.java:4)
    at pages.TextEditorTabPage.<init>(TextEditorTabPage.java:4)
    at pages.VisualEditorTabPage.<init>(VisualEditorTabPage.java:4)
    at pages.TextEditorTabPage.<init>(TextEditorTabPage.java:4)
    at pages.VisualEditorTabPage.<init>(VisualEditorTabPage.java:4)
    at pages.TextEditorTabPage.<init>(TextEditorTabPage.java:4)
    at pages.VisualEditorTabPage.<init>(VisualEditorTabPage.java:4)
    at pages.TextEditorTabPage.<init>(TextEditorTabPage.java:4)
    at pages.VisualEditorTabPage.<init>(VisualEditorTabPage.java:4)
    at pages.TextEditorTabPage.<init>(TextEditorTabPage.java:4)
```

Where

> VisualEditorTabPage. -> TextEditorTabPage.

repeats potentialy infinite times.

What am I doing wrong and how I can fix that?

Comment: This has nothing to do with testing. It has everything to do with you having two classes which create instances of each other on construction. To create an instance of TextEditorTabPage, you need to create an instance of VisualEditorTabPage - and vice versa. We don't know why you've got that cyclical relationship, but that's the cause of the problem.

Comment: Each of the two classes creates a new instance of the other class; they ping-pong creating instances of each other until the world blows up. Don't do that.

Comment: @JonSkeet and Dave Newton Thanks for the answer!
Well, this relationship is needed because Visual uses Text's methods, and Text uses Visual's methods

To do it in a right way, do you think that I should just make some methods static? Instead of instantiating classes?

Answer (score 0):

Each class requires an object of the other. Therefore when you try to create an object of class TextEditorTabPage, it tries to create an object of VisualEditorTabPage. But VisualEditorTabPage requires an object of TextEditorTabPage to create. Here generates a loop.

What is your exact requirement?

Comment: I want to be able to use some Text's methods in Visual, and some Visual's methods in Text class.

Should I make required methods static? Or there is other solution?

Comment: @Misha For your understanding benefit, learn difference between is-a and has-a relation. Secondly are these two classes related to each other somehow? Like does one class add or improve functionality of other? For example class `Animal` has method `makeSound()` which prints _sound_. Now class `Cat` will extend class `Animal` and `makeSound() ` will be overrided to make sound _Meow_. Otherwise yes, static methods will help.

Answer (score 0):

> Visual uses Text's methods, and Text uses Visual's methods To do it in a **right way**, do you think that I should just make some methods static? Instead of instantiating classes?

The right way would be to use the advantage of the Inheritance. Say you have:

- `Entity A` that have methods `aA`, `aB` and `aC`
- `Entity B` that have methods `bE`, `bF`, `bG`

You want `Entity A` to use `bF` and `Entity B` to use `aB` and `aC`

So you could deign `Entity C` in the way it would have `aB`, `aC` and `bF`.

Then your `Entity A` would extend `Entity C` with `aA` and `Entity B` would extend `Entity C` with `bE` and `bG`.